# Regex that the text field must contain a word and commas separated

Tags: regex, validation

I want a user to enter input text like `2,3,4 bhk or 2,3,4 bhk`

i.e, the user must enter the text such that there must be a `comma after each digit` and the field must `end with bhk`. Here it may contain space between 4 and bhk like `4 bhk` or may not contain space.Space is not mandatory.And after bhk no text must be entered.

Comment: how many comma seperated numbers should be allowed.

Comment: What... have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
(?:\d+,)*\d+\s*bhk$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nK7dY6/1)

Note: This allows, for example, `12,34,56 bhk`. If you really want a comma after every digit, take out the first two `+`s:

```
(?:\d,)*\d\s*bhk$
```

Comment: Nice, and just a note for any future readers, `(?:\d+,)*\d+` == `\d+(?:,\d+)*`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP's example allows for that -- there's no comma after the final digit. And OP does not specify how many digits there must be.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Right, but how does your example demonstrate a problem here?

Comment: +1, that worked. :) Small suggested tweak: since the OP is validating the whole input, how about a `^` at the beginning of the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would be,

```
^\d(?:,\d)+\s*bhk$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aR7cV5/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?:,\d)+` a number preceded by comma one or more times.
- `\s*` space character zero or more times.
- `bhk` Matches the string `bhk`
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could be:
`^(\d,)*\d\s*bhk$`

Comment: This is the same as [the other answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24968373#24968373)

Comment: @Unihedron It's technically shorter ;) Anyway, I didn't know he posted when I posted it.